# Matching words from a file exactly in PHP

Tags: php, match

I'm trying to see if words in a string match words in a file exactly. So say I had a sentence:

"I love football"

```
foreach ($match as $macthes)
{
    if (stripos("I love football",$match) !== false) {
        break;
    }
}

do something here
```

The above method works, it would find love and then do what I want it too, however it also works when someone types a shorter version of the word, so say I was searching for "pleased" but someone only put in "please" it would show a result and I don't want that.

Is there any way I can only run my method if an exact match is found?

Answer (score 1):

To find a complete word you can use a regular expression with the word boundary character: `\b`

```
if (preg_match('/\b'.preg_quote($emotion).'\b/', $value['message'])) {
```

The important part is to put `\b` both before and after the word or phrase you are looking for, this denotes a word boundary:

> A word boundary is a position in the subject string where the current character and the previous character do not both match \w or \W (i.e. one matches \w and the other matches \W), or the start or end of the string if the first or last character matches \w, respectively.
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Or more simply for how we're using it: The characters before & after the string match must be something that doesn't continue the word. Such as beginning or end of the file/line, or whitespace, punctuation, etc.

We're also using the [preg_quote](http://php.net/function.preg-quote.php), to make sure that if any of the `$emotion` values include special characters they are escaped so that they don't alter the meaning of the expression.

Comment: that has improved it, but im still getting matches on words like "to" and i have "touched" in my emotions file

Answer (score 0):

Below function will search the word in all the file of the directory. `$matches` array will give you all the files in which the word is found. I guess it may help.

```
foreach (glob("<directory>/*.txt") as $search) 
{
    $contents = file_get_contents($search);
    if (!strpos($contents, "text")) 
        continue;
    else
        $matches[] = $search;
}

if(sizeof($matches) == 0)
{
    echo "Word not found";
}
else
{
    echo "Word found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach ($emotions as &$emotion) {
 $words = file_get_contents('completeEmotions.txt');
 $word = strpos($words, $value['message']) ? true : false;
  if ($word) {
      echo 'word found';
  } else {
      echo 'word not found';
  }
}
?>
```

Use this and then in your text file, have each word on a separate line, example

word1

word2

word3

and so on...